# iOS csv to sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, csv

I am a newbie and working on code below. As a result of creating NSMutableDictionary from CSV file I am passing the value to DatabaseManager class and there is a method which receives the values and trying to insert it to the database. 
1. How can I insert those values to DB?
2. Is is efficient way to make little dictionary Application on iOS? (I have approx 40000 records and size is about 3MB)

1. MAIN CLASS

   ```
   ...

   NSString *filePath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"csv"];
   NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

   //NSString *path1=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"JapMon" ofType:@"csv"]  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
   NSArray *messArr=[content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

   if(messArr)
   {
       NSLog(@"%d", [messArr count]);
       for(int i=1;i<=[messArr count]-2;i++)
       {
           NSMutableDictionary *d=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
           NSString *StrValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[messArr objectAtIndex:i]];
           StrValue=[StrValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
           StrValue=[StrValue stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
           //  Here give whatever saperator you need to saperate data
           NSArray *arr=[StrValue componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
           //NSLog(@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex:2]);


           [d setValue:[arr objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"word"];
           [d setValue:[arr objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"hansa"];
           [d setValue:[arr objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"def"];

           //Here add logic to insert row in your database table
           [[DatabaseManager getSharedInstance]insertInitialDataToDb:d];
           //NSLog(@"%@", d);
           //Add this dictionary "d" into database
           [d release]; //Cleanup.
       }
   }
   //[content release];
   ...
   ```

2.DATABASEMANAGER CLASS

```
    -(BOOL) insertInitialDataToDb:(NSMutableDictionary*)initialData
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into japmon (word, hansa, def) values (\"%@\")", initialData];
            NSLog(@"ok");
            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
              return TRUE;

            }
              else {
              return FALSE;
            }
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }
        return TRUE;
```

Comment: My database is using Full Text Search

Comment: Is this something you will need to do regularly, or just once on first launch?  Is this data is fairly static, it's probably better to import the CSV into a SQLite DB file ahead of time and include the DB file rather than doing all of this in code.

Comment: Why don't you use Core Data?

Comment: This is just for the first launch and it will be static for the next update of app version.

Comment: @Johny I think think you're nevertheless better off with core data because it fetches everything you need right when you need it. It would blow up you app if you load all those 40,000 records into memory. So you would need to cache them and that is something that core data automatically does for you.

Comment: @HAS thank you for your prompt reply. I will try CORE DATA.

Answer (score 0):

From your query you would like to insert values to three column. But you are passing only dictionary.

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into japmon (word, hansa, def) values (\"%@\")", initialData];
```

you need to change you stringWithFormat with this

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into japmon (word, hansa, def) values (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\"), WORD_COL_VALUE,HANSA_COL_VALUE,DEF_COM_VALUE];
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my question on my own. The best way was prepared FTS sqlite database not importing after creation of "core data" database. As a result my app autocomplete/suggestion performance is at most 3.2MB CPU usage @ more than 50.000 records in UTF-8 format on simulator like a windspeed.